# My header is too big on iphone and breaks the layout, can't adjust it to small screen

Tags: css, iphone, width

So this is my website:

[www.votgaus.com/tourbillon](http://www.votgaus.com/tourbillon)

On every screen but the iphone, everything seems to work fine. The title (TOURBILLON in yellow on the header) has `letter-spacing`, which on desktop is quite difficult to appreciate for some reason, but on the iphone it's quite a lot.

In any case, what happens is on eh iphone, the word is too big and makes everything break:

[iphone layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu4IO.png)

I've tried many things. Setting `max-width`to a div, and putting the header text (`<h1>`) inside (and calling the div `.limitheader`); tried `-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;`inside prettyh much every container or anhywhere I could; using `@media`to determine how it should style on an iphone...

I think I might have messed them all, or simply not doing the right thing. If anyone can give me a solution, as long as it works (and keeps the size just fitting the iphone screen), that would be awesome. I also don't understand why doesn't the rest of the content simply fill up to the right. Anyways...

UPDATE:
I wasn't updating the right CSS file. Now the problem seems to be this: I can't asign different values to the `letter-spacing`in `@media(min-width:768px)`and `@media(max-width:767px)`. If I assign different values, it takes the one from the bigger screen size and applies it in every size.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <div class="limitheader"><h1>TOURBILLON</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F9C000;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Conduit';
    color: #F9C000;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100vh;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;


}

.limitheader {
    max-width: 100vh;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #F9C000
;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }



    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Conduit';
    color: #F9C000;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100vh;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;


}


    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The transition on `font-size` helps keeps the size change less jarring. The media query keeps the text viewable on all but the tiniest of screens.

```
header h1 {
  transition: 0.3s font-size;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size: 21px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing. It's so weird.

i've even tried :

`header h1 {
  transition: 0.3s font-size;
}``

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 21px !important;

  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
} `

Comment: aright, I' stupid. I've been editing the wrong CSS document, and updating the one I wasn't changing. Now stuff happens at least when I change it. It's still not working. I'm going to edit the post with the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, problem solved. I forgot to close a bracket. Althought some things are still unanswered...

CSS

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F9C000;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    letter-spacing: 20px;

}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Conduit';
    color: #F9C000;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;



}

.limitheader {
    max-width: 100vh;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #F9C000
;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }



    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

}
@media(max-width:767px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }


header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Conduit';
    color: #F9C000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;

  }

}
h1 {
    max-width: 100vh;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}


    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

}
```

`